# PostgreSQL new Date Format

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, format

I am trying to format my date column to 'YYYYMM' from 'YYYY-MM-DD'.

My code:
SELECT to_char(date '2015-06-01', 'YYYYMM');

I'm not sure if this worked or not because the date still looks like the original format. Also, will the new 'YYYYMM' format be applied to data that is imported in this table?

Comment: Please elaborate your question

Comment: Take a look at the postgresql [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-formatting.html) for your reference.

Comment: cast as char, substring etc.

Comment: No, the data will remain in the correct internal format.

Answer (score 2):

The `date` type is implemented as number of days from 2000-01-01 - and this number has not any visual form - it is just the offset. You can change the visualisation, that is used when the data are visualized.

```
postgres=# set datestyle to ISO;
postgres=# select current_date;
┌────────────┐
│    date    │
╞════════════╡
│ 2015-11-11 │
└────────────┘
(1 row)

postgres=# set datestyle to GERMAN;
postgres=# select current_date;
┌────────────┐
│    date    │
╞════════════╡
│ 11.11.2015 │
└────────────┘
(1 row)
```

There are other auxiliary functions for formatting date `to_char` and processing date string `to_date`. The set of styles available for `datestyle` is limited. More `datestyle` is global variable and using it can increase a risk of unwanted defects in application - so the usage of `datestyle` is not preferred.

```
postgres=# select to_char(current_date, 'YYYYMM');
┌─────────┐
│ to_char │
╞═════════╡
│ 201511  │
└─────────┘
(1 row)
set datestyle to iso;
postgres=# select to_date('201511','YYYYMM');
┌────────────┐
│  to_date   │
╞════════════╡
│ 2015-11-01 │
└────────────┘
(1 row)
```

By default the data are communicated from Postgres to client in text format. So the usage of these formatting functions (functionality) has impact on received data (from database) on client side. `to_char` does explicit convert to text type, so any client can read it (because it have to be able to read text).